# How to get user's list of Events they are attending from FBSDK (Swift 4, iOS)

Tags: ios, swift4, fbsdk

I keep getting back an empty array from the FBSDK even though my user account in Facebook is marked as attending 4 upcoming events.

Here is my code

```
func loadEvents() {
    let parameters = ["fields": "id, name, place"]

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/events", parameters: parameters).start { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error")
            print("Error getting events \(String(describing: error))");
        }

        print(result)
        if let result = result as? [String: Any] {
            if let data = result["data"] as? NSArray {
                //print(data)

            }
        }
    }
```

And the result im getting in data is the following:

> ["data": <__NSArray0 0x60c00000b410>(
>
> ) ]

Any help appreciated. Is this a permissions issue? or am i passing in the wrong parameters object?

Comment: What does checking the value of the `result` block at the start of the closure show you?

Comment: The same result.  But i just solve the issue. See below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it was a permissions issue.  I needed to add the user_events permission when login.

`loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "user_events"]`